# How to get mutual (concomitant) days between two dates interval on Java 8?

Tags: java, date, java-8, intervals, date-range

Im trying to find a way I can get concomitant days between two specific dates intervals. What I mean is:

- I have 2 intervals e.g. from **2019/10/20** to **2020/03/10** and from **2020/02/01** to **2020/05/18**.
- Which method to get number of days between those?
- It should return **~38 days** from **2020/02/01** to **2020/03/10**.

Comment: And what is the issue, on what part are you stuck?

Comment: I don't get why I got downvote. Btw I am still learning dateutils on Java 8. I know getting days between two dates, but I didn't figure out concomitant days between two intervals.

Comment: I downvote because I see no effort from you since you haven't provided any code, as the question stands it is basically a request that we should write the code for you. Please visit the Help Center and read [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 3):

First, represent your dates as `LocalDate` objects.

Take the later of the two start dates. 2020-02-01 is later than 2019-20-20, so take 2020-02-01. `LocalDate` has methods `isBefore` and `isAfter` for determinig which is later. Also take the earlier of the two end dates. In your example 2020-03-10. Now if the dates you have taken are in the wrong order — the later start date is after the earlier end date — then there is no overlap between your two intervals and the answer is 0. Otherwise find the number of days between the two dates in the way shown in the other answer.

Comment: thanks, I think you gave me a really good orientation in what to do next.

Comment: @CarlysonViana Tip: The [`LocalDateRange`](https://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org.threeten.extra/org/threeten/extra/LocalDateRange.html) class from the [*ThreeTen-Extra*](https://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) project helps with the comparison step outlined in this Answer.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I can tell, if you ensure b1 is after or the same as a1, you only need to check 2 cases: when b2 <= a2 and when b2 > a2

```
public static int checkDates(LocalDate a1, LocalDate a2, LocalDate b1, LocalDate b2)
{
    //Make sure a starts before b
    if (a1.isAfter(b1)) {
        return checkDates(b1, b2, a1, a2);
    }

    // At this point b1 >= a1

    // No overlap?
    if (b1.isAfter(a2)) return 0;

    // b2 <= a2
    // a1--------a2
    //   b1----b2
    if (a2.isAfter(b2) || a2.isEqual(b2)) {
        return (int)ChronoUnit.DAYS.between(b2, b1);
    }

    // b2 > a2
    // a1--------a2
    //   b1---------b2
    return (int)ChronoUnit.DAYS.between(a2, b1);
}
```

TODO: Add some checks to ensure `a1` is before `a2` and `b1` is before `b2`.

Comment: thanks, you also gave me an answer similar with Ole's. I can now figure out what should I do.

Comment: @OleV.V. True. Added a few more conditionals.

Comment: @OleV.V. Good point. I have simplified. I think it handles all cases.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Java-8 [ChronoUnit.DAYS.between](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/temporal/ChronoUnit.html#between-java.time.temporal.Temporal-java.time.temporal.Temporal-) as shown below:

```
import java.time.LocalDate;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;
import java.time.temporal.ChronoUnit;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        DateTimeFormatter format = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy/MM/dd");
        String strStartDate = "2020/02/01";
        String strEndDate = "2020/03/10";
        LocalDate startDate = LocalDate.parse(strStartDate, format);
        LocalDate endDate = LocalDate.parse(strEndDate, format);
        long days = ChronoUnit.DAYS.between(startDate, endDate);
        System.out.println(days);
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
38
```

**[Update]**

You can compare dates to find out if the date intervals are concomitant.

```
import java.time.LocalDate;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;
import java.time.temporal.ChronoUnit;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        DateTimeFormatter format = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy/MM/dd");

        String strIntervalOneDate1 = "2019/10/20";
        String strIntervalOneDate2 = "2020/03/10";
        LocalDate intervalOneDate1 = LocalDate.parse(strIntervalOneDate1, format);
        LocalDate intervalOneDate2 = LocalDate.parse(strIntervalOneDate2, format);
        LocalDate earlier1 = intervalOneDate1.compareTo(intervalOneDate2) <= 0 ? intervalOneDate1 : intervalOneDate2;
        LocalDate later1 = intervalOneDate1.compareTo(intervalOneDate2) > 0 ? intervalOneDate1 : intervalOneDate2;

        String strIntervalTwoDate1 = "2020/02/01";
        String strIntervalTwoDate2 = "2020/05/18";
        LocalDate intervalTwoDate1 = LocalDate.parse(strIntervalTwoDate1, format);
        LocalDate intervalTwoDate2 = LocalDate.parse(strIntervalTwoDate2, format);
        LocalDate earlier2 = intervalTwoDate1.compareTo(intervalTwoDate2) <= 0 ? intervalTwoDate1 : intervalTwoDate2;
        LocalDate later2 = intervalTwoDate1.compareTo(intervalTwoDate2) > 0 ? intervalTwoDate1 : intervalTwoDate2;

        long days = 0;
        if (later1.compareTo(earlier2) >= 0) {
            days = ChronoUnit.DAYS.between(earlier2, later1);
        } else if (later2.compareTo(earlier1) >= 0) {
            days = ChronoUnit.DAYS.between(earlier1, later2);
        } else {
            System.out.println("The given dates are non-concomitant");
        }
        System.out.println(days);
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
38
```

Comment: thanks mate, you are the real MVP.

Comment: tbh, It wasn't my question. I know getting days between two dates. Could you read my question again?

Comment: @CarlysonViana - I've updated my answer. I hope, I've understood your requirement clearly and the solution meets it. Feel free to comment in case of any doubt/issue.

Comment: Your logic is far from complete.